# sorting dojox mobile ListItem against label

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.mobile

I want to sort dojox mobile `ListItem` by label alphabetically. The label in my DOM looks like:

```
<div class="subject">Sort alphabetically against me only</div>
<span class="bomtype"> don't sort against me. </span>
```

I want to sort by the text in the label having `class="subject"` in ascending order. I am using Dojo 1.9.1.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to have your list item in some kind of dojo store(ex ItemFileReadStore) that has sort functionality, and create the list widget programatically.

Comment: @tik27 can you please show me the some  reference code because I am very new to dojox.

Comment: An example can be seen here:https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/RoundRectDataList.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList or dojox/mobile/RoundRectStoreList, for instance:

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList"
    data-dojo-props='store: store, query:{}, queryOptions: {sort: [{attribute: "label", descending: true}]}'></ul>
```

Note that, as documented, EdgeToEdgeDataList and RoundRectData list are deprecated in Dojo 1.9.

Comment: Sorry Adrian, its not working...it says error "ReferenceError: store is not defined in data-dojo-props"...thanks

Comment: Of course, you need to define the 'store' object in your Javascript code, did you do that? Just follow the example in dojox/mobile/tests/test_EdgeToEdgeStoreList.html (for instance), or the examples in http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList.html.

Comment: yes I haven't defined 'store' but the link you provided has no information

Comment: I've pointed to a test/sample and the reference documentation of EdgeToEdgeStoreList, which both provide concrete examples of defining the store. For some reason, the link to the reference doc is broken, trying again: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList.html (the first two examples cover the programmatic and the markup use-cases).