# Rendering DOM at run time is not working in Dojox

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, dojo

What I am doing  here  is, I am rendering DOM(having check box) in a div (id="euiview") programmatically . my code is like

```
var iHtml='<span><input type="checkbox" id="cbox" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.CheckBox" onclick="toggleCheckbox()" class="addremove-check"><label for="cbox"> E&amp;U Imperatives </label> </span></p><p><span><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.CheckBox" class="addremove-check"><label for="cbox1"> Transform the utility network </label></span></p>';

domConstruct.place(iHtml,"euiview");
```

where I have a div in html page is like.

```
  <div id="euiview" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

    </div>
```

Now the problem is I am unable to check or un check the check box in some android device browsers but it is working fine in desktop browser. can I render html this way or I need to create DOM programmetically? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on when you're parsing your page. If you parse your page **after** you add the new HTML, there will be no problem. However, if you parse your page **before** you add the new HTML, Dojo won't parse that DOM into widgets and so your checkbox won't work.

I assume you're parsing the page on DOM load, so it really depends on what's getting executed first. A solution that might work is the following:

```
var iHtml='<div id="new-content"><p><span><input type="checkbox" id="cbox" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.CheckBox" onclick="toggleCheckbox()" class="addremove-check"><label for="cbox"> E&amp;U Imperatives </label> </span></p><p><span><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.CheckBox" class="addremove-check"><label for="cbox1"> Transform the utility network </label></span></p></div>';

domConstruct.place(iHtml,"euiview");
parser.parse("new-content");
```

With this, you can make sure that the new content is parsed. I also noticed that you're closing your `</p>` tag but you didn't put a `<p>` in front of it.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, This is the exact answer I was looking for. I was using  parser.parse(); only and it was throwing exception. Thanks!

Comment: If you could help me to the question, I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114247/sorting-dojox-mobile-listitem-against-label